# Passing lambda function that captures temporary variable by reference in another function

Tags: c++, lambda, scope

```
void func(const int temp) {
  auto lambda_func = [&temp]() {
    return std::make_unique<int>(temp);
  }

  return another_func(lambda_func);
}
```

In this piece of code, `temp` is captured by reference in the lambda function and the lambda function is passed as an argument into `another_func`. I am not sure of what the scope of `temp` is in this case since it's a reference to a variable that exists only in `func`.

So once we are inside `another_func`, does the `lambda_func` that is passed in still have access to the original `temp` or does the behavior become undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp` goes out of scope and gets destroyed when execution returns from `func`.

`func` calls `another_func`. After `another_func` returns, `func` itself returns.

`func` returns only after execution returns from `another_func`.

Therefore, all references to `temp` remain valid for the entirety of `another_func`'s execution. This object does not go out of scope and get destroyed until after `another_func` returns.

Note that if `lambda_func`, together with its captured by reference object gets copied, or otherwise remains in scope after `func` returns, then its captured reference now refers to a destroyed object, and any reference to it becomes undefined behavior.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph: it seems `another_func` in this case accepts the `lambda_func` as pass by value, so it seems the lambda will be copied. I'm a bit lost on the "together with its captured by ref object gets copied." How would the `temp` object get copied in this case when it's being captured by reference?

Comment: Actually, I'm not 100% sure if the `lambda_func` is being copied. The signature of `another_func` is:
```std::vector<double> another_func(std::function<std::unique_ptr<int>()>  lambda_func)```
It seems `std::function` does create a copy of the lambda?

Comment: The reference itself gets copied. Whether or not `lambda_func` itself gets copied or not cannot be determined based on the code shown. In either case, its immaterial to the basic fact that `temp`, whether via the original reference or any copied reference remains in scope during the entire execution of `another_func`. It does not matter.

Comment: temp doesn't go out of scope it is copied into the address allocated by make_unique.
lambda_func will still be available on the stack and can be used in the next function call.